# Dark mode values are referenced even though night mode is not set

Tags: android, android-theme

The application is referring to the values from values-night folder even though the dark mode is not set.

> colors.xml file in values-night folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="application_background_color">#000000</color>
</resources> <!-- $Id$ -->
```

> color.xml in values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="application_background_color">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources> <!-- $Id$ -->
```

But this is not reproduced every time though. It is getting reproduced intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
 class MyApplication : Application() {

          override fun onCreate() {
                super.onCreate()
                val nightModeEnabled = //get value from shared prefs or wherever you are storing this flag
                if (nightModeEnabled) {
                    Timber.d("Manually instantiating WebView to avoid night mode issue.");
                    try {
                        WebView(applicationContext)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Timber.e("Got exception while trying to instantiate WebView to avoid night mode issue. Ignoring problem.", e)
                    }
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                }
          }
        }
```